# Freeze after resumption from suspend

Tags: suspend, release-juno

If I place my computer in "suspend", whatever application that juno is running will freeze upon waking from suspend. Strangely, If I let juno suspend on timeout, without intervention, the application works fine upon waking. The bug only appears when I place the computer in suspend manually.

Comment: Did you submit this to the bug tracker?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like there is a known bug in the current 4.15 Kernel release which Juno is running according to the below article.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395562

can you post your kernel version?

open terminal and run.

```
uname -r
```

or

```
uname -a
```

upgrading to 4.17 for the user in the above thread seems to have resolved their issue but this is not the current stable version of the kernel for Juno for what ever reason.

check out the link posted to see if this is the same or is related to your issue.

hope this helps.

""Cheers
G